# Add lists to DF / Expand string to new column and data

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I have a CSV file with a column that contains a string with vehicle options.

> ```
> Brand     Options
> Toyota    Color:Black,Wheels:18
> Toyota    Color:Black, 
> Chevy     Color:Red,Wheels:16,Style:18
> Honda     Color:Green,Personalization:"Customer requested detailing"
> Chevy     Color:Black,Wheels:16
> ```

I want to expand the "Options" string to new columns with the appropriate name. The dataset is considerably large so I am trying to name the columns programmatically (ie: Color, Wheels, Personalization) then apply the respective value to the row or a null value.

**Adding new data**

```
import pandas as pd
Cars = pd.read_csv("Cars.CSV")                          # Loads cars into df 
split = Cars["Options"].str.split(",", expand = True)   # Data in form of {"Color:Black", "Wheels:16"}
```

> split[0][0].split(":") # returns ['Color', 'Black']

What is an elegant way to concat these lists to the original dataframe Cars without specified columns?

Comment: Could you please provide your expected output also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare for a clean `split` by first using `rstrip` to avoid a null column, since you have one row with a comma at the end. Then, after splitting, explode to multiple rows and split again by `:`, this time using `expand=True`. Then, `pivot` the dataset into the desired format and `concat` back to the original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df,
           df['Options'].str.rstrip(',')
                        .str.split(',')
                        .explode()
                        .str.split(':', expand=True)
                        .pivot(values=1, columns=0)],
          axis=1).drop('Options', axis=1)
Out[1]: 
    Brand  Color                 Personalization Style Wheels
0  Toyota  Black                             NaN   NaN     18
1  Toyota  Black                             NaN   NaN    NaN
2   Chevy    Red                             NaN    18     16
3   Honda  Green  "Customer requested detailing"   NaN    NaN
4   Chevy  Black                             NaN   NaN     16
```